# How to write the music symbols in TeX?

Tags: music

I want to write some music symbols in TeX.

> How should I write the Bémol, dièse symbols in TeX?

Comment: → [musicography](https://ctan.org/pkg/musicography)

Comment: @Schweinebacke ; this satisfies me very well; you can post it as answer for others, who have the same question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: These are the standard symbols `\flat` and `\sharp`.

Comment: @Sandy G ; Yes you are right; I have found these symbols.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{musicography}

\begin{document}
There is a new package \texttt{musicography}, that provides easy writing of
\musFlat{} or \musSharp{} or \musNatural{} and some more music symbols.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Other solutions can be found in the answers to question: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [lilyglyphs](https://ctan.org/pkg/lilyglyphs). I used it extensively in my thesis.